# Extending currently written Klatt C program to interface with script using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, python-c-api, speech-synthesis

Currently I am using Klatt to create vowels and it was written and compiled with C http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/ai-repository/ai/areas/speech/systems/klatt/ . I automatically create the vowels using a Python program by invoking terminal commands which outputs a .wav file. This wavefile is then read from the disk by the Python program. I was either looking at writing the Klatt code in Python or if it was easy to extend the Klatt code so it returns the .wav file to a numpy array I have access too. Any suggestions on how to do this or the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to find a code example for LPC vocoder, well LPC decoder exactly which synthesizes speech by using LPC coefficients and excitation signal.
It is all so fine in theory but hard to find an example source code.
Klatt works on very similar, if not the same, mechanism.
If someone knows something useful about LPC synthesis, please, help.

A good implementation of LPC decoder in Python may substitute Klatt completely for your purpose.
But you can bind to it if you compile it as shared library object or a DLL or use piping to catch the output.

To shared/dynamic libraries you can bind using ctypes module.
To run it and read its stdout I suggest subproccess module.
But you can do it with os.popen as welll.
Then you can catch output and store it into a numpy array and do with it whatever you want.

But rewriting Klatt in Python is not a bad idea.
If you do not do that I probably will.